# What will be the best ways to create the object of another Activity

Tags: java, android

How to get the method that is present in another activity.

For eg.

**App Activity**

```
public class App extends MultiDexApplication {

    private final String TAG = "App";

    private static App app;  //Danger line of code

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        app= this;
    }


    public static synchronized App getInstance(){
        return app;
    }
    
public static void showMsg(){
   Log.i(TAG, "showMsg: Hello WOrld")
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_redeem);

        App.getInstance().showMsg(); //Showing error here

    }
```

and I got an error this

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.test1.App.showMsg()' on a null object reference
> at com.example.test1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:*)

if I extend the **AppCompatActivity** to **App** and extends it on **MainActivity** then we can easily call the method which is inside **App**

and at "private static App app;" this would be not the best way to proceed because of memory leaks.

any solution

Comment: Apart from the question if you should reference the Application, you already have a reference to it in every application. You can call `((App) getApplication()). showMsg()`

Comment: Try making method showMsg static.

Comment: @Michiel thanks for replying but the same exception I got "NullPointerException"...

Comment: @Danish it is already static method

Comment: @Shubham then simply call it using App.showMsg();

Comment: @Danish it will work but "private static App app;" this line of code is not safe at all to use because memory leak will happen or maybe the app will crash. This will not the better approach to get.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? If all you want is to print a log message, using the application object for this is unnecessary and bad practice. What's your reason to put `showMsg()` into `App`?

Comment: @Shubham I read somewhere if you initialise private static App app=null and then after initialising it(using wherever required) to value reinitialise it to null,this may prevent memory leakage.

Answer (score 0):

onCreate of Application is going to end up calling onCreate of the Activity. If you want to save the instance off in onCreate of the application, do it before you call super.onCreate(). Probably a better way to do it would be to override the no-argument constructor in Application, call super() and than save off the instance in the constructor

```
public MultiDexApplication() {
    super();
    app = this;
}
```

or

```
public void onCreate() {
    app = this;
    super.onCreate();
}
```

Also make sure your App class is listed as the class to use in the application tab in the AndroidManifest.

```
    <application android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
       android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
       android:name="your.application.package.App"
       >
```

Comment: same exception I got